# How to get records for the most recent complete 13 weeks?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a MySQL database table, with a unix timestamp field. I am wondering how to get the most recent complete 13 weeks?

**Update**
But I need to opt out the current week. So I need the last **complete**(that ended in past or today) 13 weeks.

Comment: What format is the timestamp, Date, Int / Unix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) > DATE_SUB(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp), INTERVAL 13 WEEKS)
```

If you want to exclude the current week you can do:

```
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp) < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 WEEKS)
```

Comment: Could you please help me with another issue: I need to opt out the current week. So I need the last complete(that ended in past or today) 13 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *,FROM_UNIXTIME(time) AS TS FROM MyTable WHERE TS > DATE_SUB(TS, INTERVAL 13 WEEKS)
```

Think that should work

Comment: You will get `Unknown column 'TS' in 'where clause'` error! `WHERE` clause can't refer to aliases! You have to use `HAVING` here.

Comment: Could you please help me with another issue: I need to opt out the current week. So I need the last complete(that ended in past or today) 13 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE created >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 13 WEEK);
```

Comment: Could you please help me with another issue: I need to opt out the current week. So I need the last complete(that ended in past or today) 13 weeks.